# TCPDF is not working with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf, cakephp-2.0

I found this great article:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

And it works fine with CakePHP 1.2, but I tried it with CakePHP 2.0 and the same Code results just a page with many strange characters.

Obviously there has something changed in CakePHP 2.0, but what is it?

Comment: It works for me in CakePHP 2.0! When you see some strange chars it's propably because the PDF is send to your browser and rendered as HTML instead of PDF. Can you check if there is a error notice within the "strange" chars?

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's for me, too by now... I don't know why. Probably I had some whitespaces at the end of the document, as TiCL supposed.

Comment: Also check (with FireBug) if the correct HTTP ContentType header is send for PDF!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest TCPDF works fine with Cakephp 2.0. The 'problem' you are having is mostly likely the browser displaying the PDF inline as html. It is caused by spurious whitespace at the end of controller/view files that causes the browser to assume text/html mimetype instead of PDF.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of 'breaking changes' from CakePHP versions 1.x to 2.x.

I have only looked at the TCPDF code briefly, but I would recommend you trying to update the code so that it works with 2.0. The main relevant changes are naming conventions and loading of Vendor files.

[Follow the migration guide](http://book2.cakephp.org/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html), and if you do manage to get it working, contact the author and share the code! Good luck :)